# Как обновить python с х32 до х64?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу начать рaботу с новой библиотекой, но для нее нужен питон х64, но у меня стоит х32. Пробoвал скачивать с офф. сайта https://www.python.org, но при нажатии на Downlоаd мне автоматично скачивает инсталятор х32 версии. Как обновить сам питон к х64, или где можно именно его скачать? (у меня 64 разрядная система)

Comment: На странице скачивания есть установщики для любых версий https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-380/

Comment: Х64 пайтона не существует(на сколько мне известно). Попробуйте найти альтернативу тому пакету, которым планируете пользоваться.

Comment: Набираем в поисковик "скачать python 64", переходим по первой ссылке https://www.python.org/getit/windows/ выбираем версию и качаем

Comment: @andreymal, ответы в ответы.

Comment: @rdbrg, ерунду говорите: перейдите по ссылке в комментарии выше, прокрутите вниз, и увидите установщики с пометкой x86-64.

Comment: Все советьі хороши, но если надо установить несколько независимьіх версий пайтона надо воспользоваться pyenv. С помощью него можна установить и нужньіе версии.